# Close Access in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, html, laravel, web

I am working with laravel 5.6.I wanna have a code that for example when user type /send (contact form url for example is /contact) manually in address bar (without complete the contact form) redirect him/her to contact form and show an error message there (in my view).Please help with sample code if its possible.Thanks.

Comment: This kind of questions are off-topic here. No one will write code for you before you try doing it yourself.

Comment: I tell if its possible friend ... There no need to notice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get started with authentication, you should read through [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authentication-quickstart).

Quickstart command, run:
`php artisan make:auth`

Based on your question, what you need is to assign `auth` middleware to the route you want to be redirected to `/login` page if they are not logged in yet.